# Faster loading data from SQL Query to DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, firebird

What can I do for faster load data to DataGridView from FireBird database?

I wrote something like this:

```
DataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
FbDataAdapter FbDataAdapter = new FbDataAdapter(query, FbConnection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
FbDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "table");
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
DataGridView1.DataMember = "table";
```

Time to display result in DataGridView in my application is about 5-10 second.
In application for managing database (SQL Manager Lite for InterBase & Firebird) this query is displaying results in under one second.

Comment: have you tried stored procedure?

Comment: Nope, but this SELECT with several JOINs, so how can i use stored procedure ?

Comment: Even though you specify `VirtualMode=true`, your code loads the entire data set in memory with `Fill(ds...). [The documentation of the VirtualMode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx) contains an example that shows the events and queries you need to implement for Virtual Mode to work and only load the visible data

Comment: A stored procedure won't help at all - it doesn't affect how fast data is loaded, only how long it takes to compile the query. The only solution is to *not* load all data, only the visible part by using virtualization - that's why DB management applications return data quickly, even before the application finishes executing

Comment: BTW, how much data are you loading at a time?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's about 10 000 records.

Comment: Then don't load 10K records - you can't display them at once anyway. Use paging to load only a page of data at a time, or virtualization, as shown in the docs

Comment: I thing paging is not way to me. It's must have smooth scrolling over all records. I looking for more information how use virtualization with SQL query and DataGridView.